# Using C++ to make a generic type - a template with shared implementation

Tags: c++, templates, types, parametric-polymorphism

As an example, consider a simple data structure like a linked list.  In C, it might look like:

```
struct Node
{
    struct Node *next;
    void *data;
};

void *getLastItem(struct Node*);
...
```

I'd like to have the same struct and functions, but with better type checking by declaring the type of the `data` field, which will always be a pointer to something.  An example use:

```
Node<Thing*> list = getListOfThings();
Thing *t = list->data;
t = getLastItem(list);
...
```

But I don't want to generate an implementation for every type of pointer, as happens with a normal template.  In other words, I want something more like a generic or parametric type from Java, ML, and other languages.  I just tried the code below as a test.  The untyped C-like part would eventually go in a implementation file, while the template and function declarations would be in the header file.  I'm assuming they would be optimized away and I'd be left with machine code that is about the same as the C version, except it would be type-checked.

But I'm not great with C++... Is there a way to improve this, or use more idiomatic C++, perhaps template specialization?

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct NodeImpl
{
    NodeImpl *next;
    void *data;
};

void *getLastItemImpl(NodeImpl *list)
{
    printf("getLastItem, non-template implementation.\n");
    return 0;  // not implemented yet
}

template <typename T>
struct Node
{
    Node<T> *next;
    T data;
};

template <typename T>
T getLastItem(Node<T> *list)
{
    return (T)getLastItemImpl((NodeImpl*)list);
}

struct A { };
struct B { };

int main()
{
    Node<A*> *as = new Node<A*>;
    A *a = getLastItem(as);
    Node<B*> *bs = new Node<B*>;
    B *b = getLastItem(bs);

}
```

Comment: Any halfway decent C++ compiler will avoid putting in multiple implementations if the assembly bits are all the same (as they will be for pointers). At least, MSVC++ does (which it calls COMDAT folding) ... I'm pretty sure GCC does as well.

Comment: @Billy But don't I still have to put the implementation code in the header files?  I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: @RobN: Yes -- on the other hand you're still effectively doing that. See my answer for more detailed reasons why it might be a bad idea.

Comment: @VladLazarenko: To match this, he really wants to use `std::forward_list` -- this is singly linked, after all. :)

Comment: I just made a minor edit to the question.  The list data type is an example, but not the focus of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other answers and comments said, use std::forward_list, or another existing library.  If you refuse, this is more like I would do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct NodeImpl
{
    NodeImpl *next;
    void *data;
public:    
    // we have pointers, so fulfill the rule of three
    NodeImpl() : next(NULL), data(NULL) {}
    ~NodeImpl() {}
    NodeImpl& operator=(const NodeImpl& b) {next = b.next; data = b.data; return *this;}
    // This function now a member.  Also, I defined it.
    void* getLastItem()
    {
        if (next)
            return next->getLastItem();
        return data;
    }
    void* getData() {return data;}
    void setData(void* d) {data = d;}
};

// the template _inherits_ from the impl
template <typename T>
struct Node : public NodeImpl
{
    Node<T> operator=(const Node<T>& b) {NodeImpl::operator=(b);}
    // we "redefine" the members, but they're really just wrappers
    T* getLastItem()
    { return static_cast<T*>(NodeImpl::getLastItem());}

    T* getData() {return static_cast<T*>(NodeImpl::getData());}
    void setData(T* d) {NodeImpl::setData(static_cast<void*>(d));}

    //or, if you prefer directness...
    operator T*() {return static_cast<T*>(NodeImpl::getData());}
    Node<T> operator=(T* d) {NodeImpl::setData(static_cast<void*>(d));}  
};


struct A { };
struct B { };

int main()
{
    Node<A> as;  //why were these heap allocated?  The root can be on the stack
    A *a = as.getLastItem();
    Node<B> bs; //also, we want a each node to point to a B, not a B*
    B *b = bs.getLastItem();

    B* newB = new B;
    bs = newB;  //set the data member
    newB = bs;  //read the data member
}
```

http://ideone.com/xseYk
Keep in mind that this object doesn't encapsulate next or data really, so you have to manage all of that yourself.

Comment: Okay, but if you inherit from a class that uses `void*`, then a field like `as.data` is a `void*` as opposed to an `A*`.  Would you provide wrappers for fields and not access them directly?  Ie `as.data()` as opposed to `as.data`.

Comment: A better encapsulated class gets rid of that problem.  Edited.

Answer (score 4):

This is exactly what `Boost.PointerContainer` does, check its implementation. Basically what it does is implement the specialization for `void*`, and have any other implementation forward to it `static_cast`ing the parameters in and out.

Comment: +1 -- but note the major difference -- the pointer containers store `T*` -- so they're always assured things are pointers. The standard containers (e.g. `std::forward_list`) store `T`, so they can't always make such optimizations.

Answer (score 3):

```
struct Node
{
    struct Node *next;
    void *data;
};

void *getLastItem(struct Node*);
...
```

This is common for C, but not for C++. In C++ it usually looks like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct Node
{
    struct Node *next;
    T data;
};

T& getLastItem(const Node&);
...
```

Note the important difference -- the C version has another level of indirection in order to share implementations, while the C++ version need not do this. This means the C version has another `n` dynamic memory allocations, where `n` is the number of items in the list. Given that each allocation usually requires obtaining a global lock, often has at least 16 bytes of overhead per allocation, as well as all the overhead the memory manager brings to the party, the advantage of the C++ version is not insignificant, particularly when you include things like cache locality in the considerations.

Put another way, for `Node<int>`, the C++ version stores an `int`, while the C version stores an `int *`, along with a dynamic allocation for the `int`.

This of course discounting that a linked list is a horrendous data structure 90% of the time.

If you must use a linked list, and if you must use dynamic allocation for the data members, then your idea of "replace the pointers with `void*`s" is not unreasonable. However, if you have access to a C++11 compiler (VS2010, recent GCC versions, etc.), you should put in an assert that you depend on `T` being a pointer type, using `std::is_pointer` and `static_assert`, and you should use `static_cast` rather than C-style casts in your interface methods. The C style cast would let someone do `Node<SomeTypeBiggerThanVoidPtr>`, and it would compile, but explode at runtime.

Comment: In my case T is always a pointer so I don't benefit from the separate bit layouts or allocation counts for Node<int> vs Node<T*> etc.  I am using C++11 so I will look into this static assert.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the comment you made above, where you said I would effectively be including the implementations in the header?  With the normal template, the compiler wants the entire function in the header.  Whereas with the common implementation, all it sees is an easily inline-able call to the untyped/void* version.  Right?

Comment: @RobN: It's just as easy, if not easier, to inline the template. Compilers often won't inline between translation units at all. With templates, the functions are always all in the same translation unit. You only get inlining between translation units when your compiler supports Link Time Code Generation -- I know MSVC++ supports this, and I think GCC does too. But it's certainly not easier to inline just because it's not a template. Inlining happens well after the template-ness or non-template-ness has been stripped, when it happens at all.

Comment: @Billy: If we were to define the example function `T& getLastItem(const Node&)` we'd have to include it in the header file, correct?  Whereas the untyped/void* one can be defined in a .cpp file?  Though as you mentioned above multiple instances of the template function could be merged later.

Comment: @RobN: Yes, you would put it in a header. I don't see why that really matters though. Linkers will remove identical functions from binaries in production mode.

Comment: I'm probably over-paranoid about compilation times.  Things have improved, but in the past when I started including more templates or STL, the increasing compile time disturbed my normal style of working.